# Find a probability of $L_\sigma(A) = F_\sigma(B)$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We are given set $\{1, 2, \dots n\}$ and some random permutation $\sigma$ of that set.
Sets $A, B \subseteq \{1, 2, \dots n\}$ and |$A \cap B| = 1$ and $|A| = |B| = k$
We define $L_\sigma(A)$ as the last element of the set $A$ ordered by $\sigma$,
and $F_\sigma(B)$ as the first element of the set $B$ ordered by $\sigma$.
Task is to find a probability of $L_\sigma(A) = F_\sigma(B)$.

**Example**
$n = 4$, $\{1,2,3,4\}$, $A = \{1,3\}$, $B = \{1,4\}$
Original set trasformed by $\sigma$: $\{2,\overline{3,}\underline{1,4}\}$
Overline is $A$ and underline is $B$. That's an illustration of the case when requirements rendered true.

**My solution draft**

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n-i+1} \frac 1 {n+1-i} \frac 1 n$$
where $i$ is length of $A$, $j$ is length of $B$. Fractions are chances for first/last element to end up on the the specific position.
What I'm worried about is a dependence issues, since $A$ and $B$ overlap.
I would appreciate your ideas and suggestions.

Comment: OK, now that the expressions are meaningful, you can start to define the probability space $\Omega$ and the probability distribution. Can I suppose $\Omega$ is the set of all $n!$ permutations, the distribution is uniform, and $A$ and $B$ are _given_ subsets (in particularly we know how many elements each has)? Then things depend on knowing these numbers; for instance if $|A|=|B|=1$, then the probability is $1$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen, $A$ and $B$ are random as well, but $|A|=|B| = k$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that is relevant is the ordering of $A \cup B$ produced by the permutation: all other elements are irrelevant.  If $|A| = a$ and $|B| = b$, there are $(a+b-1)!$ ways to order the $a+b-1$ members of $A \cup B$, of which $(a-1)! (b-1)!$ have  $A \backslash B$ first, then $A \cap B$, then $B \backslash A$.
So the answer is $$ \dfrac{(a-1)! (b-1)!}{(a+b-1)!}$$

Answer (score 0):

Wrong solution: the probability is $\frac1{k^2}$, because the common element has to get both the largest $\sigma$-value among the $k$ elements of $A$, and the smallest $\sigma$-value among the $k$ elements of $B$. But the events are dependent. (And $k^2$ need not divide $n!$, which should be a warning.)

Also wrong solution: the probability is $\frac1{2k-1}$, because the common element has to get middle $\sigma$-value among the $2k-1$ elements of $A\cup B$. But this forgets that the other elements of $A \cup B$ also have to go to the correct side of the common element.

Correct solution: the probability is $\frac1{\binom{2k-1}{k-1,1,k-1}}$ (that's one over a trinomial coefficient), since the colouring that $\sigma$ determines of the set $A\cup B$ into $k-1$ red elements (the lowest numbered ones), one white element (number $k$ in $\sigma$-order) and $k-1$ blue elements (the lowest numbered ones) must happen to coincide with that the one coloring the common element white, and the remainders of $A$, $B$ respectively red and blue. All colourings are equally likely, and there are $\binom{2k-1}{k-1,1,k-1}$ of them in all.

Comment: I believe you tried to make me derive solution on my own, which I appreciate. But Robert gave it out=\